# When is the database index updated

Tags: database, sqlite

If I have created an index on a column A in a table, and later i update a record for the column B from that table, will the index be reindexed or it will only be reindexed when i change the value for a record in the column A?

Answer (score 2):

Most RDBMS will update the index on-the-fly each time a value changes in column A (since that is what the index was created on).  If column B is not part of the index that was created, then any updates to it should not have any effect on the index.